# Multi-touch fails after sometime in phones having 512mb RAM

Tags: android

I have created an android app that handles multi-touch using OnTouchListener. The app works fine on mobiles with RAM > 512mb.

But in phones having RAM of 512mb the app fails in detecting multiple touches after some time.

Is there any solution to this????